# How can I unify the lifetimes between a struct and a trait?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a trait that specifies a lifetime on the trait method, and I have a structure that holds a value that also requires a lifetime. I'd like to have the struct implement the trait, which means that the lifetimes need to match up. I'm not sure how to express that, however.

```
struct Context<'d> {
    name: &'d str,
}

struct Value<'d> {
    name: &'d str,
}

trait Expression {
    fn evaluate<'d>(&self, context: &Context<'d>) -> Value<'d>;
}

struct Constant<'d> {
    value: Value<'d>,
}
```

**Attempt 1** - specifying the lifetime on the method:

```
impl<'d> Expression for Constant<'d> {
    fn evaluate<'d>(&self, _unused: &Context<'d>) -> Value<'d> {
        self.value
    }
}
```

This causes the lifetime on the `impl` to be shadowed, and I get errors like:

```
$ rustc x.rs
x.rs:18:5: 20:6 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn evaluate<'d>(&self, _unused: &Context<'d>) -> Value<'d>
x.rs:18     fn evaluate<'d>(&self, _unused: &Context<'d>) -> Value<'d> {
x.rs:19         self.value
x.rs:20     }
x.rs:19:9: 19:19 error: mismatched types: expected `Value<'d>`, found `Value<'d>` (lifetime mismatch)
x.rs:19         self.value
                ^~~~~~~~~~
```

**Attempt 2** - not specifying the lifetime:

```
impl<'d> Expression for Constant<'d> {
    fn evaluate(&self, _unused: &Context<'d>) -> Value<'d> {
        self.value
    }
}
```

This causes me to not actually implement the method:

```
$ rustc x.rs
x.rs:18:5: 20:6 error: method `evaluate` has an incompatible type for trait: expected concrete lifetime, found bound lifetime parameter 'd [E0053]
x.rs:18     fn evaluate(&self, _unused: &Context<'d>) -> Value<'d> {
x.rs:19         self.value
x.rs:20     }
x.rs:18:60: 20:6 note: expected concrete lifetime is the lifetime 'd as defined on the block at 18:59
x.rs:18     fn evaluate(&self, _unused: &Context<'d>) -> Value<'d> {
x.rs:19         self.value
x.rs:20     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to give the trait itself a lifetime parameter:

```
trait Expression<'d> {
    fn evaluate(&self, context: &Context<'d>) -> Value<'d>;
}

impl<'d> Expression<'d> for Constant<'d> {
    fn evaluate(&self, _unused: &Context<'d>) -> Value<'d> {
        self.value
    }
}
```

[Playpen](http://is.gd/6O52x8)

The reason you're getting error #1 (besides the shadowing) is that your trait is constraining `context` to have the lifetime of the return type, but not `self`. To constrain `self` you need to have a lifetime parameter on the trait itself.

The reason you're getting error #2 is simple: lifetimes are part of the type system and can't mismatch. Any generic code you write should work for *all* implementors of the trait -- and if the lifetimes are bound differently in each implementation, that won't work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot. I was really hoping that wasn't the case, as it means I have to change 100's of lines of code to track that lifetime now...

Comment: @Shepmaster yeah, in Rust you'll have to track lifetimes often if you want to avoid copying.

Comment: This fixed my issue even thought i was not using lifetimes in trait methods.  I was returning a new copy, but the trait still needed a separate lifetime from the struct i was implementing it for.  impl <'a, 'd> Duration<'d> for Start<'a>